# How can I edit assigned lists from guiding additional list?

Tags: r, list

first of all I apologise for my confusing title. My problem is about editing parameters of list that its name is changed with assigned() function. My list names are given below. after I read files with a for loop. I assigned the variable names below. But I when I try to edit them with the code below, I got that error. I believe that is because instead of the variable name, I try to call string type. That is why it gives me error.

What is the way for getting rid writing all of my files name manually when I try to edit those data frames?

Thank you in advance Tunc

```
colnames(folderlist[filecount])=c('chr','start','end') Error in
`colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("chr", "start", "end")) :    attempt
to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

folderlist
[1] "bedops_average_normal_2.bed" "bedops_average_normal_3.bed" "bedops_average_normal_4.bed"
[4] "bedops_average_normal_5.bed" "bedops_average_normal_6.bed" "bedops_average_normal_7.bed"
```

Comment: `folderlist` is a vector of strings. Strings have no columns. So you simply can't call `colnames` on string elements. You can call `colnames` only on matrix-like objects.

Comment: Run `?colnames` to read more about `colnames` function.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response :) .What should be my way of editing my current variables within a list ? What should be my format to store list names data?

Comment: Firstly, `vector` and `list` aren't exactly same in R. Lists are recursive. What you have is a vector of strings. Strings aren't variables. A list can store more than one type of object. A vector can't. [Here's](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list) a basic tutorial on lists.